# How to make PHP code check if inserted current password is correct password from MySQL database

Tags: php, html

I am making website settings form, where user could change password and email address.

My code is following:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';

$kehtiv_parool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kehtiv_parool']);
$kehtiv_parool_uuesti=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kehtiv_parool_uuesti']);
$uus_parool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uus_parool']);
$kinnita_uus_parool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kinnita_uus_parool']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$userid=$_SESSION['user'];
$current_password = mysql_query("SELECT parool FROM kasutajad WHERE kasutaja_id ='$userid'");


if ($kehtiv_parool==$kehtiv_parool_uuesti){
    if ($kehtiv_parool==$current_password){
        if ($uus_parool==$kinnita_uus_parool){
            mysql_query ("UPDATE kasutajad SET parool='$uus_parool' WHERE kasutaja_id='$userid'");
            echo "parool muudetud";
            }

        if (!empty($_POST['email'])){
            mysql_query ("UPDATE kasutajad SET e_mail='$email' WHERE kasutaja_id='$userid' ");
            echo "e-mail muudetud";
    }
    }
    else
        echo "Sisestatud kehtiv parool ei ole korrektne";

}
else
    echo "Sisestatud kehtivad paroolid ei kattu";

?>
```

When I remove some code it works:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';

$kehtiv_parool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kehtiv_parool']);
$kehtiv_parool_uuesti=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kehtiv_parool_uuesti']);
$uus_parool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uus_parool']);
$kinnita_uus_parool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kinnita_uus_parool']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$userid=$_SESSION['user'];
$current_password = mysql_query("SELECT parool FROM kasutajad WHERE kasutaja_id ='$userid'");


if ($kehtiv_parool==$kehtiv_parool_uuesti){
        if ($uus_parool==$kinnita_uus_parool){
            mysql_query ("UPDATE kasutajad SET parool='$uus_parool' WHERE kasutaja_id='$userid'");
            echo "parool muudetud";


        if (!empty($_POST['email'])){
            mysql_query ("UPDATE kasutajad SET e_mail='$email' WHERE kasutaja_id='$userid' ");
            echo "e-mail muudetud";
    }
    }
    else
        echo "Sisestatud kehtiv parool ei ole korrektne";

}
else
    echo "Sisestatud kehtivad paroolid ei kattu";
```

But now it wont check if inserted old password is correct password of user, how should I write this code to make it work? Variable kehtiv_parool holds value of current password which user inserted in html form and kehtiv_parool_uuesti is confirmation of same thing.

My HTML is following:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Seaded</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Täida väljad, mida soovid muuta</p>
<form action="seaded.php" method="POST">
<br>Uus parool<input type="password" name="uus_parool"> <br>

<br>Kinnita uus parool <input type="password" name="kinnita_uus_parool">
<br>

<br>e-mail             <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<hr>
<br>Sisesta kehtiv parool <input type="password" name="kehtiv_parool"><br>

<br>Sisesta kehtiv parool uuesti <input type="password" name="kehtiv_parool_uuesti"><br>


<input type="submit" value="Kinnita">

</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working. Provide more detail about problem.

Comment: It says always "Sisestatud kehtiv parool ei ole korrektne". Which is result of if ($kehtiv_parool==$current_password). It means that code always says that inserted password is not the one from database, even if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the row that the query returns.

```
$current_password_result = mysql_query("SELECT parool FROM kasutajad WHERE kasutaja_id ='$userid'");
$current_password_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($current_password_result);
$current_password = $current_password_row ? $current_password_row['parool'] : null;

if ($kehtiv_parool==$kehtiv_parool_uuesti){
    if ($kehtiv_parool===$current_password){
```

Comment: Should I make some changes in your code, when i use it in my code? The way it is right now it does not work. It still gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the encrypted pw in a session from the database once logged in
and on each page check the pw with the encrypted one and once that equals go on with the page
else clear the sessions and redirect to the index page (for example the login page)

Comment: that is a bad idea! You should just be checking an entered password against one that is stored in the database. If you store it in the session there is no guarantees that it is secure! All passwords should be stored in a database field hashed using a salt (search google if ur not sure), then when you compare you just need to hash the password in the same way. But do not ever store it in the session!

Comment: Oh so you want to keep checking it in the database so every page will load a bit slower. which will also turn out with a database overheat at multiple users connecting